# Why is my component's input value not being updated when I screen.debug()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm doing a simple test where I type in a number into an input box, this
then triggers the `onChange` event handler. However when I do this
and `screen.debug()` the input's value has not changed.
Not too sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The output I expect is input's value to equal `6` rather than `0` .
I am using React and React Testing Library.

Example is as follows

JSX file

```js
import * as React from "react";

function FavoriteNumber({ min = 1, max = 9 }) {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);
  const [numberEntered, setNumberEntered] = React.useState(false);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setNumber(Number(event.target.value));
    setNumberEntered(true);
  }

  const isValid = !numberEntered || (number >= min && number <= max);
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="favorite-number">Favorite Number</label>
      <input
        id="favorite-number"
        type="number"
        value={number}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <div role="not">{number}</div>

      {isValid ? null : <div role="alert">The number is invalid</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export { FavoriteNumber };
```

test file:

```js
test("Renders an error message when has a number outside of range", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  render(<FavoriteNumber></FavoriteNumber>);

  const input = screen.getByLabelText(/favorite number/i);
  await user.type(input, "6");

  const theNumber = screen.getByRole(/not/i);
  screen.debug(theNumber);
  screen.debug(input);
});
```

output from running test:

```html
  console.log
    <div
      role="not"
    >
      6
    </div>

      at logDOM (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/pretty-dom.js:108:13)

  console.log
    <input
      id="favorite-number"
      type="number"
      value="0"
    />

      at logDOM (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/pretty-dom.js:108:13)
```

If I do a `expect(input).toHaveValue(6)` it works, however `screen.debug()`
displays a different value.

any help is appreactiated

Answer (score 0):

When you do `const input = screen.getByLabelText(/favorite number/i);`, you are not getting the value of the input text box.

Instead what you are getting is called a `DOMNode`. This represents a node in the DOM (Document Object Model) tree.

> The DOM Node interface is an abstract base class upon which many other DOM API objects are based, thus letting those object types to be used similarly and often interchangeably. As an abstract class, there is no such thing as a plain Node object. All objects that implement Node functionality are based on one of its subclasses. Most notable are Document, Element, and DocumentFragment.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

If you do a `console.log` of the node, you shall get the value:

```
<input
    id="favorite-number"
    type="number"
    value="0"
/>
```

which is the HTML representation of this node.

If you need to get the value from this node, you can use `input.value`:

```
screen.debug(input.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fireEvent()` instead. Here's a [working solution (CodeSandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/debug-input-value-incorrectly-kxdk2h?embed=1&file=%2Fsrc%2FFavNum.test.tsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt777ujl02622a66qpqzp0kw%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt777ujl025z2a668iq3bojn%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt777ujl02612a66y3lrq5sm%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt777ujl02602a66szswjdf6%2522%257D%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B55.82779259%252C44.17220741%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt777ujl025z2a668iq3bojn%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt777ujl025z2a668iq3bojn%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt777uni026l2a66mu3foyzp%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FFavNum.tsx%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A21%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A21%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A7%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A100000006%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt777uni026l2a66mu3foyzp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clt777ujl02602a66szswjdf6%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt777ujl02602a66szswjdf6%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt75boio002p2a66ewkgrb21%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt75boio002p2a66ewkgrb21%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clt75bpbn001ldhf87vexc0i4%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt79dcuu037u2a66zb1v7quw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clt777ujl02612a66y3lrq5sm%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt777ujl02612a66y3lrq5sm%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt79d4lq03552a6650mu1usz%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt79d4lq03552a6650mu1usz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clt79d5ht002bdhf8b5gihknk%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

```js
// await user.type(input, "1");                       // debug() says "0"
fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "1" } });  // debug() says "1"
```

As a general rule, use `fireEvent()` as a fallback if `user-event` doesn't work, as said [here in the docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events).

Weirdly enough, this problem only occurs when input has `type="number"`. With every other type you should stick to `user-event`.

Here's a [Github Issues comment](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/411#issuecomment-1000592151) of someone mentioning the same solution.